Movie involving a competition between students from different universities
My memory is fuzzy about this movie, but somehow after more than 20 years it is somewhere alive in my brain, I remember:

probably us-movie from the 80s
a group of students on a holiday trip in a shabby van
they drink a lot of beer 
they come from a university with low prestige, but they are proud about it
they stay at a camping site with other vans
in one of the vans are musicians dressed in the way of KISS
there is a competition between them and students from a university with high(er) prestige involving some watersport 
the leader is a dark haired white person with cool remarks 


Up the Creek fits the description:




wow, perfect, thank you very much, that s it!
